# How do I make my main character move towards an object? LibGDX/Java

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d, collision-detection

What I want to happen is for my player to bounce from spring to another. For example take the illustration below:

[image]

Here's my code (what I've tried to do so far). This gets called in an `update()`method

```
public void springCollision(Box containsSpring) {
        // player object
        Player player = ((Player) this.object);
        // first spring
        Spring boxSpring = containsSpring.getSpring();
        // second spring
        Spring platformSpring = containsSpring.getPartnerPlatform().getSpring();
        // if player collides with first spring
        if (player.getRect().overlaps(boxSpring.getRect())) {
            // distance in x between first & second spring
            float dx = platformSpring.getxPos()
                    + platformSpring.getSprite().getWidth()
                    - boxSpring.getxPos() - player.getSprite().getWidth();
            // distance in y between first & second spring
            float dy = platformSpring.getyPos() - boxSpring.getyPos();
            Vector2 directionToSpring = new Vector2(dx, dy);
            // normalise vector then set player speed 
            player.setxSpeed(directionToSpring.nor().x);
            player.setySpeed(directionToSpring.nor().y + player.getGravity());
        }
    }
```

What currently happens is that when he jumps onto a spring his jump just continues but in slow motion for some reason. Can anyone see why my algorithm doesn't work? Let me know if the comments are unclear

Comment: You mean he never falls back down? Perhaps your gravity is 5 and your spring is 10 and so your gravity never catches up. Where are you telling it you are in the air and no longer springing?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is you are setting the player’s velocity to the value of the unit direction vector. Unit vectors have an overall magnitude of 1 and the x and y components will have some value between 0-1. That would explain why your player moves so slowly if your speed in the x direction is less than 1 and in the y direction the main factor affecting speed is probably the gravity if that is a number larger than 1. So you need to multiply the direction vector by some force/velocity value.

How you determine that value depends on how you want the player to react to the spring. Do you want the player simply keep moving at the same speed he hits the spring at and only change direction upon hitting the spring? Or do you want the spring provide the force to the player to launch him into the next spring? Or maybe some combination of the two, like how fast the player hits the spring determines how hard the spring launches him in the other direction? The simplest approach would be to keep the same speed and only change direction, so that is a good place to start which you can then build on.